# Google Maps Data API vs Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, gdata-api

What is the difference between [Google Maps Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/) and [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)?

I noticed the former is deprecated but it is not replaced by the latter. It seems to me these two APIs are meant to do separate things, but it's not clear what that is.

I want to create a private clone of the public Google Maps and add custom annotations to search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps Data API was deprecated in favour of Google Fusion Tables, and provides a means whereby you can store data in spreadsheet-like tables and do a lot of clever stuff such as geocode addresses, and export as kml, query the data etc.

So, Google Fusion Tables provides storage for your data.

Google Maps API provides you with online mapping tools which can be used to display or capture information - which you could then go on and store in Fusion Tables.

Comment: Do I need to use Fusion Tables if I mirror Google Maps and allow my users to comment on existing landmarks? Is "Google Fusion Tables" in any way tied to "Google Maps" or is it meant to store generic geographic data?

Comment: AFAIK, the only link between them is that they have an API, you have to learn both APIs to get the best out of them. Fusion Tables are optimised for storing geodata as I said, and is ideal for storing lots of data about a point. You could just store the data in your own database if you wanted to.